# How to set image into uiwebview?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, webview

[image]

I have created a html code like see above and the code uploaded to http://www.ged.Ic.com site.

Added an image name “1.jpg” into Xcode project.

When open iPad app loading http://www.ged.Ic.com/page/  from webview.

How to get to set image from into Xcode project to **img src="image path from xcode"**

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *imageFileName = @"image";
NSString *imageFileExtension = @"png";

NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageFileName ofType:imageFileExtension];

NSString *imgHTMLTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src=\"file://%@\" />", imagePath];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *imageUrlString = @"http://www.gstatic.com/translate/intl/ru/logo.png";
NSString *yourText = @"Some text here";

NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src='%@'/><br><b>%@</b>", imageUrlString, yourText];    
[myWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```